# Adaptive sampling leads to evidentiation of rendering tiles

Tags: rendering

As you can clearly see in the picture (especially on the floor), after activating ADAPTIVE SAMPLING, I have now the tiles clearly visible in the render.
This happens after I raised the thresholds.
If I leave it to AUTO in its option fields, it ruins the whole image when using the denoiser and low samples.
In general I find this feature rather destructive instead than productive.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will likely get better results by using **either** the Denoiser **or** Adaptive Sampling - instead of activating both at the same time.

The reason for this is that the Adaptive Sampling feature stops rendering an individual tile when the noise of those samples gets below a threshold, while the denoiser attempts to deal with any noise present over the whole render. By using both at the same time it’s resulting in varying levels of noise in adjacent tiles and the denoiser cannot cope with it, resulting in edge of tile artifacts.

Comment: Turning off adaptive sampling, however, significantly increases the render time, almost 3x for one of my scenes. Is that expected?

Comment: @Ajay, yes - the adaptive sampling effectively stops the rendering of tiles when it determines that the noise is below the threshold. Switching off adaptive sampling will result in all tiles using the full number of samples and this will therefore take longer. The adaptive sampling basically provides a shortcut to finish a render tile early, speeding up the render.